# Quoting and Setting $@ to a Variable

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, quotes

I am having trouble resolving how to use double quotes to capture command line arguments in a bash script. I have two files: `hello_world` and `hello world` (notice the space in the second filename).

Of course this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls "$@"
```

```
$ ./quoted_args.sh hello_world "hello world"
hello world hello_world
```

However, none of the following (very similar) scripts work:

Script A:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES="$@"
ls "$FILES"
```

```
$ ./quoted_args.sh hello_world "hello world"
ls: hello_world hello world: No such file or director
```

Script B:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES=$@
ls "$FILES"
```

```
$ ./quoted_args.sh hello_world "hello world"
ls: hello_world hello world: No such file or director
```

Script C:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES="$@"
ls $FILES
```

```
$ ./quoted_args.sh hello_world "hello world"
ls: hello: No such file or directory
ls: world: No such file or directory
hello_world
```

Script D:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES=$@
ls $FILES
```

```
$ ./quoted_args.sh hello_world "hello world"
ls: hello: No such file or directory
ls: world: No such file or directory
hello_world
```

I feel like I have tried every way of doing this. I would appreciate any help or insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `$@` into an array to be able to use it *safely* in other commands:

```
# populate files array
files=("$@")

# use array
ls "${files[@]}"

# or directly use "$@"
ls "$@"
```

Also better to avoid using all uppercase variable names in shell scripts.

Comment: @ZachKirsch Nothing really. They are typically used by the shell and applications though so you may overwrite something else.

Comment: Unix shells use all UPPERCASE environment variables e.g. `PATH, LINES, LANG` etc and you might override one of them while using all uppercase variables.